# Use laravel raw queries with dingo/APi + Fractal/transformers with laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, dingo-api

I have an ArticleCommentsController with an index method

```
class ArticleCommentsController extends BaseController
{
    public function index($id)
    {

        $comments = DB::table('comments')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
            ->where('comments.article_id', '=', $id)
            ->get();

         return $this->response->item($comments, new CommentTransformer);
    }
}
```

This is the transformer class

```
namespace App\Transformers;

use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class CommentTransformer extends TransformerAbstract{
    public function transform($comment)
    {
        return $comment; //simplified
    }
}
```

The response is the following error:

```
get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given.
```

Obviously, i need to send an instance of the comment object when calling Fractal\transform but i don't know how to do that since laravel's raw queries only return an array or an instance of the QueryBuilder class.

Comment: Try removing the `->get()` from your query

Comment: @smartrahat. i did that but then it returned an instance of the QueryBuilder Object and returned this error: `Argument 1 passed to Dingo\Api\Http\Response\Factory::collection() must be an instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection, instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\escape\app\Http\Controllers\ArticlesCommentsController.php on line 41 and defined`

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the `item` method on the `response` object seems to require and object and not an array. Using the `array` method will work, but won't use any transformer you pass.

So, I think you might get away using `ArrayObject`, as follow:

`return $this->response->item(new ArrayObject($comments), new CommentTransformer);`

Remember to put a `use ArrayObject;` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

this was very time long ago but I write the answers for this guy or others or me in the future if I lost my memory hahaha

```
class ArticleCommentsController extends BaseController
{
    public function index($id)
    {

        $comments = DB::table('comments')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
            ->where('comments.article_id', '=', $id)
            ->get();

         return $this->response->collection(Collection::make($comments), new CommentTransformer);

    }
}
```

of course you need add this to the controller ArticleCommentsController

```
// Dingo
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;

//Convert query to collective
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

//Transformers for API
use App\Transformers\CommentTransformer;
```

and  this inside your controller before your functions

```
//Use for Dingo Helpers
use Helpers;
```

All together:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Response;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// Dingo
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;

//Convert query from LMS lbrary to collective
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

//Transformers for API
use App\Transformers\CommentTransformer;

class ArticleCommentsController extends BaseController
{

    //Use for Dingo Helpers
    use Helpers;

    public function index($id)
    {

        $comments = DB::table('comments')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
            ->where('comments.article_id', '=', $id)
            ->get();

         return $this->response->collection(Collection::make($comments), new CommentTransformer);

    }
}
```

Regards!, I hope this help to others in the future :D

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps ,it works out:

1.change

`return $this->response->item($comments, new CommentTransformer);`

to

`return $this->response->collection(Collection::make($comments), new CommentTransformer);`

2.Transfomer class

```
namespace App\Transformers;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class CommentTransformer extends TransformerAbstract{
     public function transform($comment)
     {
         return [
            'id' => $comment->id,
            ...
         ];
     }
}
```